# Place UIView on top of all other views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uikit

Can someone help me on how to make make UIView created in code to be on top of all other view? where tableView is the parent view and the subSelectionView is my custom siblings view, I want to make it on top of the tableView.. I have this code below:

This is the full source code for my didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, from where I programmatically add UIView instance..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    // Execute upon selection
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [[tableView viewWithTag:199]removeFromSuperview];

    // Get the cell size
    CGSize cellSize = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].frame.size;

    // Contact Details Container
    UIView *subSelectionView;
    if(indexPath.row < [contacts count] - 6)
        subSelectionView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, (int)cellSize.width - 20, (int)cellSize.height + 130)];

    subSelectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    subSelectionView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    subSelectionView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    subSelectionView.alpha = 0.9;
    subSelectionView.tag = 199;
    subSelectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;


    // Contact Name Container
    UIView *contactNameSubSelectionView;
    if(indexPath.row < [contacts count] - 6)
        contactNameSubSelectionView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, (int)cellSize.width - 20, (int)cellSize.height)];

    contactNameSubSelectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    contactNameSubSelectionView.alpha = 0.5;

    [subSelectionView addSubview:contactNameSubSelectionView];


    // Contact Name Label
    Contacts *contact = [self.contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *contactName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@ %@ ", contact.fname, contact.lname];

    UILabel *contactNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, (int)cellSize.width, (int)cellSize.height)];
    contactNameLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;

    [contactNameLabel setText: contactName];
    [contactNameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [contactNameLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]]];
    [contactNameSubSelectionView addSubview:(UIView *)contactNameLabel];


    // Buttons
    UIButton *buttonMobile = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, cellSize.height + 10, 30, 30)];
    buttonMobile.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    [buttonMobile setTitle:@"..." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonMobile addTarget:self action:@selector(btPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlStateNormal];

    [subSelectionView addSubview:(UIView *) buttonMobile];



    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]insertSubview:subSelectionView aboveSubview:self.view];   
    [self.parentViewController.view bringSubviewToFront:subSelectionView];


    [tableView reloadData];

}
```

but does not work..

The image below shows my subSelectionView, the button is within it and the subSelectionView is within the tableView. Now, when I clicked that button, the problem is that I can't actually click it. It focuses directly to the tableView even with the presence of my codes. Can someone help me please?....

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I read your question right your problem is that you can't actually tap on the button in your new view that's on top of the tableview?

And when you tap it, the UITableView below responds?

This means that the UIButton does not recognize it is tapped, and the event goes to the next subview below it to be processed.

Now, there are many possible causes for such behavior - you may have user interaction disabled for it or the **UIView**, it may it's *Enabled* property set to NO or it may be beyond the bonds of the **UIView** (iOS automatically assumes that if a tap is outside of the bounds rectangle it missed the receiver).

Also, taps are ignored if your alpha is set to 0.0.

You should check all of the above.

Comment: Thanks pete.. I had already reviewed it and set the button enabled property to yes but still does not work.. hmmm.. am I right using this code: [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]insertSubview:subSelectionView aboveSubview:self.view];?

Comment: If you can see the subview, then yes - the problem is that it does not receive events.

Answer (score 53):

There is a method bringSubViewToFront of UIView instance. You can use that method.

e.g.

```
UIVIew *yourSubView;
[yourMainView addSubView:yourSubView];
[yourMainView bringSubviewToFront:yourSubView];
```

EDIT

in your case it should be like,

```
[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] insertSubview:subSelectionView aboveSubview:self.view];
[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] bringSubviewToFront:subSelectionView];
```

Comment: Can you please post your full source code how do you create subview and add ?

Comment: @AldeeMativo: `bringSubviewToFront:` only works with a direct subview, not any descendant view. You need to send the message to the table view cell, not the view controller's view.

Answer (score 8):

In Swift you can do this:

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(theViewToMoveToFront)
```

Comment: In Swift 4.2 it is now:
view.bringSubviewToFront(theViewToMoveToFront)

Answer (score 6):

```
[tableView bringSubviewToFront:subSelectionView];
```

or if don`t work try

```
[viewController.view bringSubviewToFront:subSelectionView];
```

Comment: thanks moonkid, still does not work.. I am still on focus with the back view.. hmm.. if I will use insertViewAtIndex: method, what is the topmost layer? is it the greatest number / value or the lowest?

Comment: You can get topest view using window object Window *window =  [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]windows]objectAtIndex:0]; Than UIView *topView = [[window subviews]lastObject];

Answer (score 5):

You could place this subview higher in the view stack. This can be easily done in Interface Builder.

[image]

Here `Label - files` is placed ontop of `Table View - all files`. Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 4):

Use `- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSInteger)index` function of `UIView` along with the **NSArray** of **subviews** which you get from UIView's **subViews** property ...